# Delete book but keep it in iBook?

Tags: mac, books

I have a lots of book in a folder but they are all in the iBooks app. Can I delete them if they are in ? I have tried with one book look like nothing happens but I want to be sure before I remove this folder.

Answer (score 1):

All purchases made from Apple can be restored if deleted by selecting "Purchases" then selecting the book and clicking on "Download".